Signature of restriction of bilinear form
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
Consider $AdS^3$ be the set $$AdS^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid b(x,x) = -1\}$$
I have proved that tangent space at $x \in AdS^3$, $T_x AdS^3 = x^\perp$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2,2} = \text{Span}\{x\} \oplus  \text{Span}\{x\}^{\perp}$
But I cannot prove $b\Big|_{x^\perp}$ has signature $(2,1)$. Can anyone please help me?

It's Sylvester's Law of Inertia: if you already have the orthogonal direct sum decomposition $\mathbb{R}^{2,2} = (T_x {\rm AdS}^3) \oplus (T_x {\rm AdS}^3)^\perp$ (i.e., $\mathbb{R}^{2,2} = x^\perp\oplus x$), then the signature is additive: $$(2,2) = (n_+,n_-) + (0,1) \implies (n_+,n_-) = (2,1).$$Here we use that the line spanned by $x$ is timelike, so its signature is $(0,1)$.

Thanks for your answer.  But I have a little more doubt. Can you please explain the last line? If $b(x,x) = -1$ then why signature of $\langle x\rangle$ is $(0,1)$?

If $b(x,x)=-1$, the restriction $b(\lambda x, \mu x) = -\lambda \mu$ is a negative-definite bilinear form on the line spanned by $x$.

This is the same as Ivo Terek's answer but stated a bit differently.
Construct an orthogonal basis $x, e_1,e_2, e_3$. Then what can you say about $b(e_i,e_i)$? Now note that $\mathrm{span}\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}=x^\perp = T_xAdS^3$.
